# ReactJs reselect recalculates all selectors every time

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I have a reducer that holds blog posts of various types. I'm using select to fetch part of the data that I need, yet every time the state change reselect recalculates all the selectors.

```
initialstate = {
  blogPosts: { byId: { 1: { id: 1, parent: null } }, ids: [1] },
  commentPosts: { byId: { 2: { id: 2, parent: 1 } }, ids: [2] },
  filter:{ selectedBlog: null }
};

const reducer = (state = initialstate, action) => {
  if (action.type == 'filter') {
    return object.assign(state, { filter: action.filter });
  }
  return state;
}

const Blogselector = state => state.posts.blogPosts
const Commentselector = state => state.posts.commentPosts
const getFilters = state => state.posts.filter;
```

In my component when I'm showing blog posts, I dispatch action that set `filter.selectedBlog = post.id`

The problem is when the filter changes, the whole Posts branch of state changes too as I'm returning a new copy. So any selector I will write will end up recalculating everything every time a filter changes.

What are the standard practice for creating a filtering state selectors ?

Answer (score 0):

Please show me your selector code part.

In your above code, `filter` has been changed but `blogPosts` and `commentPosts` aren't changed, so unnecessary recalculating isn't expected.